# Is there an easier prime factorization method for the sum of a prime's powers?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I need to obtain prime factorizations of numbers of the type: $\sum_{i=0}^n p^i$, for any prime number $p$ (not the same one each time).

Do you know if there is a quicker algorithm to calculate these factorizations than those used for other natural numbers?

I don't know if there is a known solution. My only lead is that all Mersenne primes are of the form $\sum_{i=0}^n 2^i$.

Edit: by prime factorization I mean, for example, if $p$ is 3 and $n$ is 6, the number is 364, and the prime factorization I'm looking for is 2^2, 7 and 13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a geometric series, so $\sum_{i=0}^n p^i=\frac {p^{n+1}-1}{p-1}$.  When the prime is $2$ this does not give a factorization because the denominator is $1$.  For all other primes it does.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't think of the formula of a geometric series, that could prove to be useful. However, I don't see how the sum obtained by this formula leads to the prime factorization of itself, which is what I am looking for. For example, when p equals 3 and n equals 3, the sum is $1+3+9+27=40$. This is obtainabled by your given formula, but my task is to find the prime factorization of that sum, i.e 5^1 and 2^3

Comment: To extend on that, when p is 3 and n is 6, the sum is 364, and its prime factorization is 2^2, 7, and 13. My question is if there is a method to find those factors that is quicker than other prime factorization algorithms

Comment: @Ifn47, you can factor the numerator $p^{n - 1} - 1$ by the same idea as $(p - 1) (1 + p + p`2 + \dotsb + p^{n - 2})$.

Comment: @Ifn47, even better, use the known factorization $x^{r s} - 1 = (x^r - 1)  (x^{(r - 1) s} + x^{(r - 2) s} + \dotsb + 1)$. Pick any factorization of your $n - 1$, and you are in bussiness.

Comment: Awesome thanks!

Comment: The sum formula i think needs to be $(p^{n+1}-1)/(p-1)$ instead; is there a way to factor that, too?

Comment: @lfn47:  yes, the sign in the exponent was a typo.  This does not give a complete factorization, it only goes one step.  vonbrand's comment applies if you can factor $n+1$.  You can get  bunch of factors that way, but still not necessarily all of them

Comment: @vonbrand, I think you had a typo too with the 2nd formula. I tried plugging in numbers and it turned out inaccurate. Could you please tell what the correct equation should have been? It seems like the right approach for this factorization and I can't find it online

Comment: Oh, found the typo. The first exponent in the right-hand side should be $s$ instead of $r$. Works like a charm. Thanks for this resource!